# Is deleting posts a good practice?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, deletions, deleted-answers

In principle, MO posts can be cited in papers; on the other hand, MO posts get deleted sometimes. There is a risk, then, of referring a MO post which no longer exists. Is deleting posts a good practice, then?

Comment: From the initial version of your post, I deduce that you are not an experienced English speaker. I therefore took the liberty to reformulate your question, in an attempt to make what you meant to ask clearer.

Comment: As mentioned in some previous discussions, one can use [Wayback Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayback_Machine) to make sure that some version remains available regardless of existence of a specific post or the MathOverflow site as a whole. For example: [Stable url for linking](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/2193) or  [Citing a mathoverflow comment](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/5288).

Comment: If you're asking mainly in connection with citing MO posts, perhaps the tag ([meta-tag:citations]) could be suitable here.

Comment: Sensible posts that are substantial enough to warrant a citation have a negligible risk of getting deleted. If one cites a post that’s so terrible that it risks deletion, they should suffer the consequences.

Comment: The initial version of the question reads as follows Title: **Is it good to delete questions?** Body: *While internet can be reffered in papers and its a math site; why do they delete some questions? Maybe someone has come by an idea in the question and its necessary for readers to refer to.*

Comment: @EmilJeřábek I dont agree with you. Maybe Galois works had no point for lots of mathematicians in his era; But then... Everyone knows what happend.

Comment: @Martin Sleziak So good